# How to map Enum 0 on hibernate for a String identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, enums, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem with a mapping of a Enum value.
In my Bonus.class I have the enum property Type with the enum class BonusType.
This is how I define my enum class (just enum definition, no methods or constructors are copied):

```
public enum EavType
{
  WORLDWIDE ("WORLDWIDE"),
  SIMPLE ("SIMPLE"),
  NOTVALID ("0");
}
```

So far so good. As far as I get a Bonus element of the type "WORLDWIDE" or "SIMPLE" from the DB there is no problem, but when I get a Bonus on the database with the type=0 I get an error:

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [0] for enum class [com.bosch.gam.commons.bo.remuneration.BonusType]
```

The problem is that I cannot set how the NOTVALID type is saved, the data I get from the database is created from another interface and they just save it as 0. I also should clarify that the Type column in the Bonus table is a VARCHAR2.

Now my question: is hibernate interpreting 0 as a number? How can I fix this?

Comment: Hibernate search for an enum named "0". If you can't control the value stored in the db then it's not a great idea to use an enum, Use a string and then map it properly to your enum if you want to be more value safe in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. The thing is that this is a web application running since 10 years... Changing it to a String would mean unendless changes :P

Comment: I was also trying to just avoid getting the 0 values from the DB with a hibernate query: `from Bonus e where e.assignment.id = :id and e.type != 'NOTVALID'` or `e.type !='0'` but none works.

Comment: If you can change the query and your enum has few values then you can decode the field "type" to return values that map your enum. In your example map the first two cases to return themselves while all the others values return "NOTVALID".

Comment: Ohh thanks, that should work. But I am not following you 100%. The default value would be on the enum or on the hibernate mapping? I am quite new to default values on enums...

Comment: What do you think about to use an AttributeConverter? See https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters

Comment: that looks like a good workaround but sadly I am not able to implement it due to compatibility. My app is on Struts 2 and spring mvc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183895/discussion-between-aris2world-and-carloshf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use an AttributeConverters ([baeldung jpa attribute converters](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters)) you can use the same approach within your bean. 
In your class "Bonus":

- create a new field of type String, e.g. dbEavType
- map this new field to the database column "type"
- implements set and get of this new field to adapt the string value to the enum value of EavType doing the expected conversion (e.g. if setting "0" in dbEavType then set NOTVALID in eavType field)

This solution allows you to adapt the value as you want and don't break other layers of your application which can continue to use the enumeration.